# Is this intuition for the etale topology essentially correct?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Suppose I have an etale morphism $f : X \to Y$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are Riemann surfaces, then this means that $f$ is a local isomorphism, so at any $y \in Y$ I can find a local inverse $g : U \to X$ where $U \ni y$ is open in the Euclidean topology on $Y$.

Now this is meaningless from the Zariski point of view, *but* since $g$ is the germ of an analytic function at $y$, I can take the entire Riemann surface $S$ associated to $g$, and consider the global analytic function $\widetilde{g} : S \to X$.  I consider this as an analogue of the map $g : U \to X$, and therefore as a partial analogue of the Euclidean open set $U$.

Is this basically the right idea?

Comment: Well, it looks like you already accept that étale morphisms are analogous to local analytic isomorphisms. That's really all there is to it – the topological intuition is that local homeomorphisms are as good as open sets for many purposes.

Comment: Can you say more about how local homeomorphisms are as good as open sets?

Comment: A local homeomorphism $X \to Y$ is basically a bunch of open subsets of $Y$ glued together. Thus, $X$ inherits any "local" properties of $Y$, and if $X \to Y$ is surjective, $Y$ inherits any "local" properties of $X$.

Comment: @ZhenLin I mean, I think the real reason is (as I would have thought you would have jumped on) they define equivalent topoi.

Comment: That's only part of the story. There is a still larger class of continuous maps that generate the same topos – the "locally sectionable" maps – but the topological meaning is less clear there.

Comment: @ZhenLin Do you mind clarifying? As far as I know it's just true that the topos defined by local homeomorphisms (the étale morphisms) defines an equivalent topos to the topos of opens on $X$. This tells you (this is for Daniel's sake, not yours) that the cohomology essentially agrees, and thus one might as well use the étale topology for cohomology computation. Since the étale topology in AG more readily resembles the étale topology in topology (than 'Zariski' topology) it gives a more reasonable belief that it's cohomology is of an essentially 'topological nature'. Thanks!

Comment: @ZhenLin Oh, I see. I misread your comment at first. I think that understanding this is not necessary—as long as we are dealing with a topos which is capturing the topological information, I don't think it's necessary to understand other sites giving the same topos.

Comment: No, I can't agree. The fundamental ideas behind Grothendieck topologies find more applications than just in cohomology theories.

Comment: @ZhenLin Do you care to give an example? It's most likely just my lack of mathematical worldliness, but I've only ever seen sites used in a) cohomology theories, and b) stacks.

Comment: @ZhenLin I created a room so as to not clutter the comment section. Please join if you are so inclined! http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29095/grothendieck-topologies-uses